# What is the right SQL command in Derby?

Tags: sql, derby

I would like to know where the "limit" and "order by" words have to go. I have these:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM NAMES LIMIT " + limit + " ORDER BY ID ASC;";
sql = "SELECT * FROM NAMES LIMIT " + limit + " ORDER BY ID DESC;";
```

Also is there a command like "select top percent" in Derby?

Comment: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/rrefsqljoffsetfetch.html#rrefsqljoffsetfetch

Comment: Dislike. No info about order it in ascending or descending way.

Comment: The documentation clearly shows that LIMIT is not part of the syntax in Derby.  The SQL standard does not support these clauses, and different DBMS implement them differently, with the different names and different positions for limits on the number of rows to fetch, and on the number of rows to skip.  The documentation explicitly says "use ORDER BY to ensure repeatable results" (or words to that effect).   The last example shows the ORDER BY appearing before the OFFSET and FETCH clauses.